# How to Load next form in MDIparent's panel on clicking button on current loaded form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MDIparent1 form having panel1, form1 having a button Form1BtnNextForm and form2 having also a button Form2BtnPrevForm. when MDIparent1 is loading, form1 is added to the controls of panel1. I want to remove form1 and add form2 in the controls of panel1 when clicking button Form1BtnNextForm on form1. After adding Form2 if button Form2BtnPrevForm on Form2 is clicked then the Form2 is removed and Form1 is again added to the controls of panel1.

```
//Code for MDIparent1

public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.TopLevel = false;
        f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Show();
    }
}

//Code for Form1

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1BtnNextForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

//Code for Form2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2BtnPrevForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

//Code for Programe

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MDIParent1());
    }
}
```

Now what i should be to write in Form1BtnNextForm_Click and Form2BtnPrevForm_Click.

Comment: `Next` and `Previous` buttons and `main Panel` should be on parent form, and then do same thing as you do in parent load form

Comment: it's ok, But i want to transfer control from button on a form as question stated above.

Comment: Do you have added `panel1` into `Form1` and `Form2` as well?

Comment: What is the need to add panel1 in form1 and form2 ? panel1 is added in MDIparent1 and forms should be added in the controls of panel1.

Comment: Also, this is not really MDI. when working with MDI you don't add the child form as a control to your panel, instead you should set `IsMDIContainer` to `true` on the parent form and `MDIParent` to the parent form on the child form